# Least Square means in GLMM?

Tags: r, modeling, glmm, lsmeans

I applied a GLMM model to my data. Trip duration was modelled as a function of the presence of a data logger (i'm working on birds), a factor with two level (present/absent), random effects: bird identity and nest identity, family=gamma.  The GLMM show no data logger effect, and now I want to plot means. Since the sample design is unbalanced I used least square means based on the GLMM model, but they are completely different from raw means:

Real mean (logger on): 258 , Real mean (logger off): 260 , LS mean (logger on):5.49, LS mean (logger off): 5.56

Am I doing something wrong since they are so much different, or it's common to have such different values from raw means and I can just plot LS means?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **lsmeans** package, the annotations below the output in fact say that the results are reported on the log scale. If you add the argument `options = list(type = "response")` to the `lsmeans` call, the results will be back-transformed to the response scale.

Here's an example (where in this case the link function is the logit):

```
> library(lme4)
> example(glmer)
    ... (output not shown) ...
> library(lsmeans)
> lsmeans(gm1, "period")
 period    lsmean        SE df asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL
 1      -1.398343 0.2312140 NA -1.851514 -0.9451717
 2      -2.390268 0.3073939 NA -2.992749 -1.7877869
 3      -2.526559 0.3270801 NA -3.167624 -1.8854938
 4      -2.978088 0.4251647 NA -3.811396 -2.1447808

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> lsmeans(gm1, "period", type = "response")
 period       prob         SE df  asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1      0.19807921 0.03672693 NA 0.13569523 0.2798569
 2      0.08391784 0.02363110 NA 0.04775454 0.1433443
 3      0.07401714 0.02241761 NA 0.04040242 0.1317591
 4      0.04842565 0.01959184 NA 0.02163870 0.1048199

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```

Comment: Thank you very much, on the annotation below the output it was not specify that the results were in log scale, but using type "response" they are back transformed.

Comment: I added an example illustrating the annotations. Perhaps you need to update your packages.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without more detail, but the best guess would be that you're getting lsmeans reported on the log scale.

> Real mean (logger on): 258 , Real mean (logger off): 260 ,
>
> LS mean (logger on):5.49, LS mean (logger off): 5.56

```
exp(c(5.49,5.56))
## [1] 242.2572 259.8228
```

These are in the ballpark.  The other thing you have to watch out for are Jensen's inequality effects if the random-effects variances are large.

Comment: Thank you very much, they were reported on a log scale! I will have also a look to Jensen's inequality effects, thanks for the tip